# margin in css doesn't work

Tags: html, css

I have Table and I want to put it in the middle of the page.  If I set align attribute to center, it works but I want to do that with CSS. Here is my CSS:

```
center vorder, td
{
  border-color:Blue;
  border-style:double;
  color:#8A2BE2F;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;

}
```

and this is my table code:

```
<table class="center vorder" >
<tr><td colspan="4">mittige Tabelle</td></tr>
<tr><td>Element 0 0</td><td>Element 0 1</td><td>Element 0 2</td><td>Element 0 3</td></tr>
<tr><td>Element 1 0</td><td>Element 1 1</td><td>Element 1 2</td><td>Element 1 3</td></tr>
<tr><td>Element 2 0</td><td>Element 2 1</td><td>Element 2 2</td><td>Element 2 3</td></tr>
</table>
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: There is a point for classes in CSS, isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From that code, your css is not even getting used. It should be something like:

`.center.vorder, td`

or

`.center.vorder td`

..depending on what you want to target.

Also you have `margin-left: auto` twice, so remove one. You can do it in one line like so:

`margin: 0 auto;`

Answer (score 3):

Your CSS syntax is off.

```
table.center
{
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;

}

td {
  border-color:Blue;
  border-style:double;
  color:#8A2BE2F;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you missing syntax, need to prefix class with "."

```
.center.vorder, td
{}
```

Refer working fix http://jsbin.com/azoxes/1/edit

Answer (score 1):

You sould use `.` for class in CSS:

```
.center.vorder
{
  border-color: blue;
  border-style: double;
  color: #8A2BE2F;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

If you want center the td's text you shuld use this:

```
td
{
    text-align: center;
}
```